# Click anywhere to type

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I am interested in creating my very own control from scratch. (Yes, I know...) - here's what I was thinking, I'll only choose one of the following, but depending on the complexity, I think I am going to go with a TextBox or ComboBox:

1. TextBox
2. ComboBox
3. FormTyper

I made the third name up. FormTyper is simply a "way" of being able to click absolutely anywhere on the Form and just start typing, and the letters/numbers etc will appear as if you were typing in a textbox. This would be my ideal new project, I would love to do this, but I haven't seen it done before, and I'm not sure how to start.

Does anyone have any advice, suggestions, or really good, in-depth (but simple :P) tutorials/articles/code I can read up on/play around with?

Any help at all will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Jase

Answer (score 2):

You picked the wrong kind of control to get started with.  Making your own text editor from scratch is unreasonably hard.  Seemingly simple things like displaying a caret requires pinvoking obscure api functions.  Calculating where to show it inside of a string is very hard.

Pick an easier one to get started with.  A calendar for example.  Essential skills you'll learn is how to write your own OnPaint() method to give a control a visual appearance, how to do mouse hit testing and how to pick the right kind of events and properties to make the control useful in a program.

Comment: Hmmm... Fair enough, Calendar Control it is then :D I'll look around for stuff about this - Would you recommend any articles?

Comment: In the search box on the upper right, type [winforms] +controls +tutorials